# How to remove only one item from the LocalStorage onClick?

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I want to delete only one item from my local storage on a click action, but it doesn't work, when I choose to delete one item, all the values are deleted.

I created a deleteItem function

```
deleteItem = (ev) => {
        let nums = localStorage.removeItem('myNums');
        let arr = [];
        if(nums){
            arr = JSON.parse(nums);
            arr.push(this.state.num);
            arr = Array.from(new Set(arr));
            localStorage.removeItem('myNums', JSON.stringify(arr));
        }else{
            arr=[];
            arr.push(this.state.num);
            localStorage.removeItem('myNums', JSON.stringify(arr));
        }
        this.setState({isSaved:true});
```

to execute my function I call it on the click to the button :

```
<button onClick={this.deleteItem}>Delete this card</button>
```

This button is available for each value for my list, let's say I have 1, 2, and 3 when I click on delete item for 3 , I lost the three values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LocalStorage is a key-value store, if you remove the item with key `myNums`, nothing's left there. Since `removeItem` doesn't return the removed item, you need to first get the item, then overwrite the value in localStorage with a new array containing the new values

```
const nums = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('myNums'));

if (nums) { //nums exists, concat the new value
  localStorage.setItem('myNums', JSON.stringify(nums.concat(this.state.num)));
} else { //save empty array to localStorage
  localStorage.setItem('myNums', JSON.stringify([]);
}
```